# Intersection Observer observes when useEffect is mounted for the first time but fails to observe when useEffect is remounted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend, intersection-observer

```js
import React, { useState,useRef,useEffect } from "react";
import FloatingText from "./Components/FloatingText"
import Navbar from "./Components/Navbar"
import Models from "./Components/Model-S"
import Model3 from "./Components/Model-3"
import Modelx from "./Components/Model-X"
import Modely from "./Components/Model-Y"
import SolarPanel from "./Components/Solar-Panel"
import SolarStorm from "./Components/Solar-Roof"
import "./App.css"
import bgimagee from "../assets/taun-stewart.jpg"


function App() {
 
  console.log(window.screen)
  const [data,setData] = useState([])
  const [intersectionData, setIntersectionData] = useState([]);
  const [text, setText] = useState("Default Text"); 
  const [maintext,setMainText] = useState()
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

 
  const ref = useRef()
  
  useEffect(() => {
    
    setData((data)=>[...data,ref.current]);
  }, [setData]);



  useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
      (entries) => {
        setIntersectionData(entries);
      },
      { threshold: [0, 0.3, 0.6, 1], rootMargin: "0px" }
    );

    

    
      data.forEach((dataa) => {
        observer.observe(dataa);
      });
    

    setIsLoading(false);
    

    return () => observer.disconnect();
  },[data]);

  
 useEffect(() => {
  intersectionData.forEach((entry) => {
      
      const { intersectionRatio } = entry;
      
      if (intersectionRatio >= 0.6) {
        // Change the text when the element crosses the 0.6 threshold

        setText("New Text");
        
        console.log(text)
      } else if (intersectionRatio >= 0.3) {
        setText("Medium Text");
        console.log(text)
      } else {
        setText("Default Text");
        console.log(text)
      }
    }); }, [intersectionData]);



console.log(data)


  return (
    <div  className=" w-screen h-screen bg-cover bg-no-repeat" >
     <Navbar/>
    <div ref={ref}  id="home" className="w-full h-full  z-0" style={{
        backgroundImage: `url(${bgimagee})`,
      }} ></div>
     <Models data={data} setData={setData} />
     <Model3 data={data} setData={setData} />
     <Modelx  data={data} setData={setData} />
     <Modely  data={data} setData={setData}/>
     <SolarPanel data={data} setData={setData}/>
     <SolarStorm data={data} setData={setData}/>
     <FloatingText maintext={maintext} setMainText={setMainText} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In this code I'm trying make sure that whenever any entry reaches threshold it should console.log(text). It does when I mount it first time during building of the code but after refreshing the website when it is supposed to remount, it fails to console.log(text)

I think I'm doing something wrong with useEffect hook

Here is link where you can observe as well update my code

https://codedamn.com/project/tesla-clone/code/PssQI88lIveSFpfO-oIMy

Comment: What do you mean by this: "but after refreshing the website when it is supposed to remount, it fails to `console.log(text)`"? As in when you refresh the preview? I'm not able to reproduce this. When I press refresh then scroll, things seem to log as normal. I also opened the preview in its own tab and attempted the same reproduction steps (refresh then scroll) and the logs for `text` still appear.

Comment: You may need to make a screen recording, preferably in a GIF format so that you can attach it to your question without having the find a 3rd part video host ([reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248249/is-it-possible-to-embed-videos-in-questions)).